# Visual Studio 2008 Navigation Bar Confused

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, ide

I am refactoring a (rather long) C program using Visual Studio Professional 2008 (9.0.30729.4462 QFE).  I use function picker drop-down in the navigation bar to jump between functions in the source quickly.

I added a function to the top of some source code and now the function picker drop-down in the navigation bar is just wrong.  It sometimes jumps me to a different function, or inside another function.

I've tried cleaning, building, rebuilding the project, closing and reopening the project and even rebooting my computer, and nothing fixes this.

My supposition is that the IDE needs to rebuild its source code index, but I've been searching to no avail to location such a file much less how to force a rebuild.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised that rebuilding your code didn't put it in place.
You could try deleting your .suo file (which visual studio stores in the same location as your .sln).  This stores a bunch of user options specific to that solution file, so you may want to back up your .suo file in case something goes all the way bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the .ncb file and reopening the solution should fix the problem.

Visual studio parses your source code and stores the results inside the .ncb (Intellisense database). The file is used for auto-completion, class-view browser, etc... It usually rebuilds automatically, but sometimes it needs a manual clean.

Comment: That fixed it!  Thanks!  You just saved me a bunch of time!